# How do I avoid duplicate rows in SQL none of the JOIN commands are working for the query

Tags: sql

I recently created a query that list ARP for a computer & the drives mapped to the computer Everything comes back but the 2nd table is causing the 1st table to list duplicates. When it runs if the user has 4 network drives it lists the application 4 times, If the user has 5 drives it list the application 5 times & so on. My query is below along with the example output.

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  v_Add_Remove_Programs_Alias.DisplayName0,
  v_Add_Remove_Programs_Alias.Publisher0,
  v_Add_Remove_Programs_Alias.Version0,
  v_GS_MAPPEDDRIVES.mappedletter0,
  v_GS_MAPPEDDRIVES.mappedname0,
  v_GS_MAPPEDDRIVES.servername0,
  v_GS_MAPPEDDRIVES.dateinventoried0
FROM fn_rbac_Add_Remove_Programs(@UserSIDs) v_Add_Remove_Programs_Alias
JOIN fn_rbac_R_System(@UserSIDs) v_R_System_Alias
  ON v_Add_Remove_Programs_Alias.ResourceID = v_R_System_Alias.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN v_GS_MAPPEDDRIVES
  ON v_R_System_Alias.ResourceID = v_GS_MAPPEDDRIVES.ResourceID
WHERE v_R_System_Alias.Netbios_Name0 = @computername
AND v_Add_Remove_Programs_Alias.DisplayName0 NOT LIKE %SOMEAPP%
ORDER BY v_Add_Remove_Programs_Alias.DisplayName0
```

Output:

| Display Name | Publisher | Drive | Server | Sharename | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Microsoft Word | Microsoft | A: | Servername1 | Share1 | Date |
| Microsoft Word | Microsoft | A: | Servername1 | Share1 | Date |
| Microsoft Word | Microsoft | A: | Servername1 | Share1 | Date |
| Microsoft ABC | Microsoft | B: | Servername2 | Share2 | Date |
| Microsoft ABC | Microsoft | B: | Servername2 | Share2 | Date |
| Microsoft ABC | Microsoft | B: | Servername2 | Share2 | Date |

Comment: How do you propose showing this? You need a seperate table that lists network drives that is not in the same table as the list of applications.

Comment: I was using using SRSS via SCCM . But now I read your comment it looks like I have been just spinning wheels trying to get this to work. Thanks

Comment: In SSRS you can definitely show two different tables.